# How do I highlight keyword in vim in terminal?

Tags: vim

I wanna highlight boost keyword in my vim

For example, the word 'timer' is in white in original file.
And I add the following in my cpp.vim

```
hi def Boost_keyword term=italic cterm=italic gui=italic guifg=Magenta ctermfg=Magenta
```

Now it's in magenta in gvim, but not in terminal.

My question, 
For GVim, keyword 'timer' is okay. 
But how do I change in terminal, same with Gvim?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try changing the color scheme. :help colorscheme.

Comment: this is my defined keyword. I read the help already.

Comment: What happens if you remove `term=italic cterm=italic`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, you are right. It seems font cannot be italic in terminal. Would you please post your answer and I can mark it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
 term=italic cterm=italic
```

And I expect this will work. Italics and terminals rarely mix.

Also:

```
Use only one of "cterm=" OR "ctermfg=" OR "ctermbg="
```

--[`:help highlight-cterm`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#highlight-cterm)